# How to find URL, Twitter Username, LinkedIn Username, Facebook Username from a given Company Name?

Tags: facebook, twitter, semantics, semantic-web, semantic-analysis

I have a list of companies:

```
New York Times
Sony
Washington Post
Panasonic
Toyota
others...
```

For each company in the list, I need the:

```
Company URL
Twitter @Username
LinkedIn Username
Facebook Username
```

Is there an API service that does that in an automated fashion? Maybe a combination of various services could work?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the other networks, but for Facebook, you can simply locate the Page using a combination of API Search:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=New%20York%20Times&type=page
```

This will return a lot of Page IDs:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "name": "The New York Times",
         "category": "Media/news/publishing",
         "id": "5281959998"
      },
      {
         "name": "W New York - Times Square",
         "category": "Hotel",
         "id": "107574351937"
      },
      {
         "name": "The New York Times Crossword Puzzle",
         "category": "Community",
         "id": "230891537029840"
      },
      {
         "name": "The New York Times Travel Show",
         "category": "Company",
         "id": "135183981456"
      },
      {
         "name": "InterContinental New York Times Square",
         "category": "Travel/leisure",
         "id": "225795063575"
      },
      {
         "name": "Well | The New York Times",
         "category": "Media/news/publishing",
         "id": "181548405298864"
      },
 ...
}
```

For most major companies, you can probably assume that the first ID in the list is the correct page. You could check by looking up each ID like so:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/5281959998
```

You will see in response two fields that are relevant: `website` and `likes`

Likes will show the number of fans that the page have (you can probably assume that the one with the most fans is the correct page) and website will provide the company-specified URL of their website.